# Request User Permission to Post to Their Facebook Wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to request my users for their permission to post to their facebook wall using [SammyK/LaravelFacebookSdk](https://github.com/SammyK/LaravelFacebookSdk).

I have a button

[image]

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8888/facebook/checkin" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="VTBcvupobSzcDThNeNguxCR4tMh2e28Wds4LzJA8">
  <button type="submit" id="check-in-with-facebook" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-facebook">Check In</button>
</form>
```

After, they clicked on it, this controller function will trigger

```
public function checkin(){
    $fb = App::make('SammyK\LaravelFacebookSdk\LaravelFacebookSdk');
    $permissions = 'publish_actions, user_posts, user_photos';
    $login_url = $fb->getLoginUrl(['email','scope'=>$permissions]);
    return redirect($login_url);
}
```

Then, the redirect will happen to this URL below

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.5/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Ffacebook%2Flink&state=04c7d976a47fca8c370b08b9d1dd954d&scope=email%2Cmanage_pages%2Cpublish_pages%2C+publish_actions%2C+user_posts%2C+user_photos&response_type=code&client_id=956232267794396&ret=login&sdk=php-sdk-5.2.0&logger_id=aff4eaf6-269b-479a-a91c-aa53b57447d2&ext=1474663682&hash=AeYpZWVkApEd5u-N
```

Then, the modal will pop up, but I see only `Public Profile` and `Email Address`.

[image]

I requested for `publish_actions, user_posts, user_photos`

What did I do wrong ?

Any suggestions / hints will be nice ...

Comment: do you know about login review? if not, read the official docs.

Comment: login review? of what ? the frame work that I used OR the facebook ?

Comment: That you use publish_actions

Comment: @WizKid : That what I am trying to do in `$permissions = 'publish_actions, user_posts, user_photos';`

Comment: That is how you ask the user for the permission. You need to get the permission approved by Facebook before you can use it.

Comment: That what I am trying to do, and my modal doesn't seem to request for those 3 that I listed. Get it ?

Comment: You are aware that publishing permission is only asked for on the second screen of the login dialog, right?

Comment: @CBroe : When I clicked on `continue`, I don't see any second dialog box at all. I get redirect right the way ...

Comment: then do as i said and read about login review in the facebook docs

Comment: If you are testing this with a user that has a role in the app, then it should work fine. If you want to be able to ask other users for the permission, then you need to get it reviewed by Facebook first.

Comment: @CBroe: Hmm.. okay. Now, things are started to make sense, when you said, `“user that has a role in the app”` - what  do you mean by that ?.

Comment: @CBroe:  `“If you want to be able to ask other users for the permission, then you need to get it reviewed by Facebook first”` - That is exactly what I am trying to do. How do I get Facebook to review it ? Is it hard to do ? Any further direction on this will mean a lot to me.

Comment: @luschn : I'm so sorry that I didn't know what you mean in the first time, now I do. I am looking at this now : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review